# Access VBA set recordset of lists not working

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset

I've come across an interesting problem and can't figure out the resolution. This code has been working flawlessly until a week ago. For some reason it will not work on my computer, works on every other computer though. Now when I run the code below it tells me 'ActiveX component can't create object'.

```
If Not rs.EOF Then
    Set Me.DropDownList.Recordset = rs <-Fails here
    Me.DropDownList.Requery
End If
```

It's doing this now on every control on every form, but again just on my computer. I have verified that the controls are set to 'Table/Query' and not value list. However, if I loop through the recordset and add the items individually, after change the row source to value list, it works fine.

The query is fine, the recordset opens fine I just can't set the recordset of a listbox or dropdownlist all of a sudden. I'm using adodb and retrieving the data from SQL server. All of that is connecting and retrieving properly.

Any help would be appreciated, I've done days of searching and troubleshooting with no success. It'd be most inefficient to have to change all the code to loops just because it's not working on my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to eventually zero in on it being an issue with a DLL or service. Did a repair of Microsoft Office, restarted and all is well again. No understanding why it happened this appears to be the solution.